# Multibinding selection parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a window with text boxes. There are two templates (two sets of data) for filling this form. User clicks radio-button and chooses a template. After that text boxes are filled by data from templates.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="Height" Width="500">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RadioButton GroupName="Templates" Content="Template1" IsChecked="True"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton GroupName="Templates" Content="Template2"></RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Field1</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="TbField1"></TextBox>

    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Field2</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="TbField2"></TextBox>

    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">Field3</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Name="TbField3"></TextBox>

    <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="BtnGetData" Content="GetData" Click="BtnGetData_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static DataSetTest data1;
    private static DataSetTest data2;

    private static DataBingings bindings;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        data1 = new DataSetTest("field1_1", "field2_1", "field3_1");
        data2 = new DataSetTest("field1_2", "field2_2", "field3_2");

        bindings = new DataBingings();
        bindings.Add(TbField1, data1, "Field1", data2, "Field1");
        bindings.Add(TbField2, data1, "Field2", data2, "Field2");
        bindings.Add(TbField3, data1, "Field3", data2, "Field3");

        bindings.SetData();
    }

    private void BtnGetData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bindings.GetData();
        MessageBox.Show(data1.Field1);
    }
}

public class DataSetTest
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }

    public DataSetTest()
    {

    }

    public DataSetTest(string field1, string field2, string field3)
    {
        Field1 = field1;
        Field2 = field2;
        Field3 = field3;
    }
}

public class DataBingings
{
    List<BindingExpressionBase> bindings = new List<BindingExpressionBase>();

    private Binding AddBinding(string propertyName, object data)
    {
        Binding b = new Binding(propertyName);
        b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        b.Source = data;
        b.ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        b.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = false;
        b.NotifyOnTargetUpdated = false;

        return b;
    }

    private MultiBinding AddMultiBinding(string propertyName1, object data1, object data2, string propertyName2)
    {
        MultiBinding mb = new MultiBinding();
        mb.Converter = new CustomMultiValueConvertor();
        mb.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit;

        Binding b = AddBinding(propertyName1, data1);
        mb.Bindings.Add(b);

        b = AddBinding(propertyName2, data2);
        mb.Bindings.Add(b);

        return mb;
    }

    public void Add(TextBox control, object data1, string propertyName1, object data2, string propertyName2)
    {
        MultiBinding b = AddMultiBinding(propertyName1, data1, data2, propertyName2);
        BindingExpressionBase be = BindingOperations.SetBinding(control, TextBox.TextProperty, b);
        bindings.Add(be);
    }

    public void SetData()
    {
        foreach (BindingExpressionBase b in bindings)
        {
            b.UpdateTarget();
        }
    }

    public void GetData()
    {
        foreach (BindingExpressionBase b in bindings)
        {
            b.UpdateSource();
        }
    }
}

public class CustomMultiValueConvertor : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[0];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value as object[];
    }
}
```

Class DataBindings contains methods for adding multibinding and inserts data to textbox or gets data from it. 
But, how can I send parameter from RadioButton to multibinding for choosing first or second binding?

Answer (score 0):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code exampl](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)e it's impossible to know what would be the best design for your scenario. You've provided not much context here, which necessarily restricts what we can know about your code. That said…

You can set the `MultiBinding.ConverterParameter` property; this sets the value that is passed as the `parameter` argument for the `Convert()` and `ConvertBack()` methods.

But note that you can't bind this to anything; it can only be set to some specific value. So you would have to update it explicitly according to the state of your radio group. Given that, it would probably make more sense to not bother with the converter, nor the `MultiBinding` itself, and just update the bindings themselves according to the radio button selection.

That is, when the radio button selection changes, simply bind *either* `propertyName1` or `propertyName2` to the desired `Text` property, according to the selection.

Of course, it is *possible* that there is an even better, XAML-declared way to do what you are trying to do. Again, without a good code example, it's really not practical to speculate on that particular point. If the above doesn't seem like what you really want to do, please consider improving the question by provide a better code example, a clear description of what that code example does, and how that's different from what you want it to do.